# Use paste/paste0 for the "key" argument in gather()

Tags: r, data-analysis, tidyr

I created a toy data frame to demonstrate my question:

```
a = 0
df = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 2:3, z = 3:4)
df %>% gather(key = "name0", value = "val", -1) # this works fine
df %>% gather(key = paste0("name", a), value = "val", -1) # but this gives an error
```

The error message was

```
Error in `ensym2()`:
! Must supply a symbol or a string as argument
```

I hope to specify the "key" column's name as `name0` but `0` can be flexibly changed by `paste0()`. I have done the searching but couldn't find a solution!

Comment: You cannot use a function call for names in gather. Consider using pivot_longer

Comment: Possible hack: `a = 0; a = paste0("name", 0); df %>% gather(key = a, value = "val", -1)`

Comment: @onyambu Thanks! ```pivot_longer()``` solved my problem!